# Handling events with C# raised from VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, raiseevent

I'm trying to manage some event.

I've my main project, written in C#, and I've added another project, written in VB.NET.

In the VB.NET project, I've a class, raising an event:

```
Public Class newMessageArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Public Property messageCode As String
    Public Property appName As String
End Class

Public Class EventRaiser

    Event NewMessage As EventHandler

    Sub MessageEvent(ByVal typeEvent As String, ByVal messageCode As String, appName As String)
        If typeEvent = "newMessage" Then
            Dim args As newMessageArgs = New newMessageArgs()
            args.appName = appName
            args.messageCode = messageCode
            RaiseEvent NewMessage(Me, args)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The method raising the event, is called from my VB.NET code, but I have to handle it with my C# code. How can I do it?

This event isn't binded to any xaml element.

CODE UPDATED:

Trying to handle the event:

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD4uB.jpg

```
attivazione.EventRaiser raiser = new attivazione.EventRaiser();

raiser.NewMessage += raiser_NewMessage; //error: "no overloads for raiser_NewMessage matches the delegate system.eventhandler", underlining red raiser_NewMessage



private void raiser_NewMessage(object sender, newMessageArgs e)
{
   //handle your event here
}
```

Attivazione is the name of the class in VB.NET that raises the event.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The language it is written in shouldn't be important. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: simply: how can I do it? How can I see the event from another project? How can declare the event handler in C# and read the parameters?

Comment: @PieroAlberto The same way you add any other event handler ever.

Comment: @PieroAlberto Are those separate projects for some?

Comment: You have updated your question with a line of code that is commented with the word `error`. Why not include the actual error in your question?

Comment: @DanielKelley added the error description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intend something like this?

```
var raiser = new EventRaiser();
raiser.NewMessage += raiser_NewMessage;

private void raiser_NewMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //handle your event here
}
```

But `newMessageArgs` class and `NewMessage` event should be public in your VB code.

And of course, you should add reference to assembly with your VB code into C# project.

Comment: @PieroAlberto Have you made newMessageArgs and NewMessage event public in your VB code? And what exactly errors you're getting?

Comment: yes, they're public, you can see it in the question.

Comment: it says that raiser doesn't contain a defition of NewMessage

Comment: @PieroAlberto Check your typing in code. In your question you've wrote `raiser.NewMesssage` - with triple 's'. If it is so in your code - that's error origin. ;)

Comment: well, you're right... but now the error is changed! :( "no overloads for raiser_NewMessage matches the delegate system.eventhandler", underlining red raiser_NewMessage

Comment: @PieroAlberto, Try to change event handler method declaration to `private void raiser_NewMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)`, it should help

Answer (score 2):

Modify your VB code to use a delegate that exactly matches 'newMessageArgs':

```
Public Delegate Sub CustomEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As newMessageArgs)
Public Event NewMessage As CustomEventHandler
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `vb.net` delegate signature is incorrect. You need to create a `NewMessage` delegate that will match your event argument.

```vb
Public Class NewMessageEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property MessageCode As String
    Public Property AppName As String

End Class

Public Delegate Sub NewMessageEventHandler(sender As Object, e As NewMessageEventArgs)

Public Class EventRaiser

    Public Event NewMessage As NewMessageEventHandler

    Public Sub MessageEvent(ByVal typeEvent As String, ByVal messageCode As String, appName As String)
        If (typeEvent = "newMessage") Then
            RaiseEvent NewMessage(Me, New NewMessageEventArgs() With {.AppName = appName, .MessageCode = messageCode})
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```